# Redrawing custom CALayer subclass on custom property change

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I am trying to build a special layer which draws text. This `TWFlapLayer` has an attributed string as a property:

`TWFlapLayer.h`:

```
@interface TWFlapLayer : CALayer
@property(nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CFAttributedStringRef attrString;
@end
```

and gets synthesized in `TWFlapLayer.m`:

```
@implementation TWFlapLayer

@synthesize attrString = _attrString;

/* overwrite method to redraw the layer if the string changed */

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"attrString"]){
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSLog(@"%s: %@",__FUNCTION__,self.attrString);
    if (self.attrString == NULL) return;
    /* my custom drawing code */
}
```

My intention was that the layer is automatically redrawn using my custom drawing method if the attrString property was changed using the synthesized setter method. However from the NSLog statement placed in the drawInContext: method I see that the layer is *not* redrawn.

By placing a breakpoint in the needsDisplayForKey method I made sure that it returns YES when asked for the attrString key.

I am now changing the attrString like this

```
// self.frontString is a NSAttributedString* that is why I need the toll-free bridging
self.frontLayer.attrString = (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef) self.frontString;

//should not be necessary, but without it the drawInContext method is not called
[self.frontLayer setNeedsDisplay]; // <-- why is this still needed?
```

I looked up the class method definition for needsDisplayForKey in the CALayer header file, but it seems to me that this is the method I would like to use or am I missing an important point here?

from `CALayer.h`:

```
/* Method for subclasses to override. Returning true for a given
 * property causes the layer's contents to be redrawn when the property
 * is changed (including when changed by an animation attached to the
 * layer). The default implementation returns NO. Subclasses should
 * call super for properties defined by the superclass. (For example,
 * do not try to return YES for properties implemented by CALayer,
 * doing will have undefined results.) */

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key;
```

**Summary**

Why is my layer not redrawing when the custom property attrString is changed and marked by `needsDisplayForKey:` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`CALayer.h` also says:

```
/* CALayer implements the standard NSKeyValueCoding protocol for all
 * Objective C properties defined by the class and its subclasses. It
 * dynamically implements missing accessor methods for properties
 * declared by subclasses.
```

Apparently the `needsDisplayForKey:` mechanism relies on CALayer's dynamically-implemented accessor methods. So, change this:

```
@synthesize attrString = _attrString;
```

to

```
@dynamic attrString;
```

Comment: That was great! That did the trick. The `CALayer.h` really is a huge file, a bit embarrassing that I missed this point.

Comment: @kurt-revis I had similar problem and @dynamic works fine, thanks. But could you explain why initial rendering does not happen for me, even though I set the initial value in `-(id)init` method. needsDisplayForKey simply doesn't trigger in `init`.